# How to move the pointer up a line while appending a text file

Tags: python, append

I understand that by appending a file using:

```
f = open("filename.txt", "a+"),
```

the pointer will be set at the last line of the file. Is there a way for me to move the pointer up one line (the opposite of `\n`) to delete/replace what's in that line before starting to append? There's something that I have to remove from the last line before adding the new content to the file.

An example I can use to illustrate what I mean is if the file contains a story, and at the last line is "*To be continued*". When I want to continue the story by appending, is there a way to remove the *"To be continued"* before writing any new content? It would also work if I could just move the pointer up one line and overwrite the "*To be continued*" with new content!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly this is not the best answer, but it works:

```
with open("filename.txt", "r+") as f:
  position = f.tell()
  line = f.readline()
  while line != 'To be continued\n':
     position = f.tell()
     line = f.readline()
  f.seek(position, 0)
  f.write("New line to be added\n")
  f.write('To be continued\n')
```

It is important to grab the position (using `tell`) **before** reading a line, so you have a pointer to the beginning of that line.